# Haskell inbuilt libraries, where does it go?

Tags: haskell, ghc, bytestring

In my `/home/sk/.ghc/x86_64-linux-7.8.4/package.conf.d` folder, there is an entry for `bytestring` package as,

```
bytestring-0.10.6.0-7682cf7d45ee92d104399a67f3bce6ba.conf
```

In my `/opt/ghc/7.8.4/lib/ghc-7.8.4/package.conf.d` folder, there is an entry for bytestring as,

```
bytestring-0.10.4.0-d6f1d17d717e8652498cab8269a0acd5.conf
```

Why does haskell store `bytestring` libraries in two different places. This is leading to compilation errors due to type/version mis-match.

How can i ensure, only one version of any library is stored and used at a time on my ubuntu 14.04 machine?

Comment: My guess: You have two packages installed- one globally and one per-user.

Comment: you should be able to manage those with the `ghc-pkg` helper - if all else fails you can always reset your installation :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why does haskell store `bytestring` libraries in two different places. This is leading to compilation errors due to type/version mis-match.

Well, no. The problem is that you have two versions of the `bytestring` library installed, period. It doesn't matter whether they are in the same package database or not.

You should fix this with `ghc-pkg unregister bytestring-0.10.6.0` (first unregistering any packages that would break, if any) and then add a line

```
constraint: bytestring installed
```

to your `~/.cabal/config` to prevent it from happening again. You probably want to do the same with other packages that came with GHC, at least all the ones that are dependencies of the `ghc` package (see `ghc-pkg describe ghc`).

I don't know if there is a way to tell cabal to never install a second version of *any* package. (In practice I find temporarily installing multiple versions of packages useful enough that I would find it more annoying than helpful.)